# How do you apply a patch for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git

I am currently running Rails with gem version 3.0.7.

So in the gem file I have

gem rails '3.0.7'

I want to apply a patch found on git rails. I also noticed that the patch is in the master branch, but I could not use the master version since it has some conflicts with other gems that I use.

So how can I apply a patch found on git to rails 3.0.7?

Thanks.

Comment: For myself the best way is to monkeypatching module/class in initializers.

Answer (score 0):

You can fork rails on github, throw away all commits you don't need (e.g. with rebase) and use the `:git` option in the Gemfile to point to your repo.